# Cross referencing in Rust - implementing MVC

Tags: rust, model-view-controller

I'm trying to implement a mvc pattern in rust, as of now, the controller has ownership of the model, and can call it's function by doing `self.model`, but I can't figure out how to reference the controller from the model itself, so it can notify the controller when changing by itself, my code looks like this:

```rust
struct Controller {
    model: Model,
}

impl Controller {
    pub fn on_model_change(&self) {
        println!("Model has changed");
        // do something
    }
}

struct Model<'a> {
    controller: &'a Controller,
    foo: i32,
}

impl Model {
    // fn to notify controller of model change
    pub fn notify_controller_change(&self) {
        self.controller.on_model_change();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let controller = Controller { model: Model { foo: 0, controller: &controller } };
}
```

I haven't implemented the view yet as I assume it follows the same logic as connecting the model to the controller.

Bind the model with the controller to notify it's change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your architecture: to create a controller you must have a model, but to create a model you have to give it reference to an existing controller. That means that you can't create a controller nor a model, because these two structs depends on each other.

The solution is to make modal optional in `Controller` struct. You can make reference to controller optional in `Model` as well. So you can create a controller without a model and then assign a model to it.

The code would look like that:

```rust
struct Controller<'a> {
    model: Option<Model<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Controller<'a> {
    pub fn on_model_change(&self) {
        println!("Model has changed");
        // do something
    }
}

struct Model<'a> {
    controller: &'a Controller<'a>,
    foo: i32,
}

impl<'a> Model<'a> {
    // fn to notify controller of model change
    pub fn notify_controller_change(&self) {
        self.controller.on_model_change();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let controller = Controller { model: None };
    let model = Model { foo: 0, controller: &controller };
}
```

This code is complex with a lot of lifetimes. I don't see a point in that message passing between model and controller and in model's awareness of controller, that owns it. It just isn't in rust's fashion.

I suggest you to create a method on controller called `change_model`. It will update the model field and call `on_model_change` method. Like shown:

```rust
struct Controller {
    model: Model,
}

impl Controller{
    pub fn change_model(&mut self, model: Model) {
        self.model = model;
        self.on_model_change();
    }

    pub fn on_model_change(&self) {
        println!("Model has changed");
        // do something
    }
}

struct Model {
    foo: i32,
}

impl Model { /* ... */}

fn main() {
    let controller = Controller { model: Model { foo: 0 } };
}
```

I hope I help you with your problem.

Comment: Ended up not using the MVC pattern, because as you said, it's not suitable for Rust. What I ended up doing was using a thread for the interface and a thread for the model, having them connected with two channels.

Comment: If you really want to use MVC patter with bidirectional message passing, just use raw pointer at that point.